# IGenericRepository<T> - Cannot resolve symbol where

Tags: c#, unit-of-work, generic-interface

I'm following a tutorial on the unit of work pattern and my code won't compile because it doesn't recognise where in the interface signature and it doesn't recognise type T.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLayer.Repository
{
   public interface IGenericRepository<T> : where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> AsQueryable();

    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>>  predicate);
    T SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T GetById(int id);

    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Attach(T entity);
}
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the extra `:`, like this:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. The code is from this blog post https://codefizzle.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/correct-use-of-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-asp-net-mvc/ and he has a typo in his code.